# Offline File & Document Management System?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm searching for a private document management system.

It should have the following features:

- Storage of files on *my* harddrive
- organizing in human readable folder structure (I want to open files in OO etc. without the management system)
- Automatic indexing of  OpenOffice, MS Word and PDF files with full-text-search
- Possibility of adding Tags and Categories to different files

It seems to me that I'm searching for a kind of a database for archiving and indexing files I put in a folder...

(Without PHP,mySQL and other software with may be abused by others....)

Comment: Does Gnome Documents serve your needs?.

Comment: Gnome Documents doesn't allow to tag documents. Furthermore saving the Metadata with the repository would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 4):

If the database must be exportable, you should search for the document management system that uses a database easily exportable and well supported as MySQL.
There are many, just to name a couple [OpenDocman](http://www.opendocman.com) and [Logicaldoc](http://www.logicaldoc.com).

Answer (score 0):

GNOME lets you tag files. For example, right-click on a file in Nautilus and go to the Tags tab.

The Unity Dash includes automatic indexing and full text search for your documents.

Documents you save end up on your own hard drive by default, in a folder structure of your choice.

In short, doesn't Ubuntu do exactly what you're asking straight out of the box? If not, please could you edit your question to make it clear exactly how your requirements do not match what Ubuntu provides already?

Comment: 1) I'm using xfce4

Comment: 2) The database should be exportable, sry, I didn't outline it in my first post